# HeaderContent setting the background colour in mudblazor

Tags: mudblazor

This is the sample code:

```
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<MudTable Items="@Elements.Take(4)" HeaderClass="@($"background:{Colors.Red.Darken1};")" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Position</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Molar mass</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position" HideSmall="_hidePosition">@context.Position</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_hidePosition">Hide <b>position</b> when Breakpoint=Xs</MudSwitch>
<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_loading">Show Loading</MudSwitch>

@code { 
    private bool _hidePosition;
    private bool _loading;
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }

}
```

The issue is I am not able to set the HeaderContent background colour, neither style nor class parameters work. I also set this one  HeaderClass="@($"background:{Colors.Red.Darken1};")" in Mudtable but that doesnot work either.

Answer (score 2):

`@($"background:{Colors.Red.Darken1};")` is not a valid class name.

Use a valid class e.g.: `HeaderClass="mud-info"` and it will work.